# Is static gauge quantization of the particle equivalent to covariant quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, constrained-dynamics

In the covariant quantization one is able to get directly (from the constraint $p^\mu_\mu+m^2=0$) the Klein-Gordon equation.
But if one uses the parametrization $\tau=X^0$ then the Schrodinger equation is not local anymore (the reason is the square root in the hamiltonian).

I think it has to do with antiparticles.
So my guess is that covariant quantization is equivalent to light-cone quantization but it is not equivalent to static gauge quantization.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250911/2451