# Why are tree-level diagrams classical?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I see this statement from time to time.

But when I look at scattering in QED or phi-4 theory, I don't understand how classical calculation can reproduce these amplitudes.

To what extent is this statement valid?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270428/2451 and links therein.