# Peskin and Schroeder's QFT eq. (9.14): Gaussian momentum field integration of phase space path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, path-integral, regularization, normalization

On Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book page 282, the book considered functional quantization of scalar field.

First, begin with
$$\left\langle\phi_b(\mathbf{x})\left|e^{-i H T}\right| \phi_a(\mathbf{x})\right\rangle=\int \mathcal{D} \phi \mathcal{D} \pi \exp \left[i \int_0^T d^4 x\left(\pi \dot{\phi}-\frac{1}{2} \pi^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2-V(\phi)\right)\right] $$
Since the exponent is quadratic in $\pi$, the book evaluates the $\mathcal{D}\pi$ integral and obtains
$$\left\langle\phi_b(\mathbf{x})\left|e^{-i H T}\right| \phi_a(\mathbf{x})\right\rangle=\int \mathcal{D} \phi \exp \left[i \int_0^T d^4 x \mathcal{L}\right]. \tag{9.14} $$
There needs to be some complicated coefficients, but the book omit here.

I am puzzled how this integral finished? ie.
$$\int  \mathcal{D} \pi \exp \left[i \int _ { 0 } ^ { T } d ^ { 4 } x \left(\pi \dot{\phi}-\frac{1}{2} \pi^2\right)\right] $$
Since now the integral argument is $\pi$, which is a function, how to understand it's upper and lower limit? Also, their have a term $i \int_0^T d^4 x$ inside the exponent. So how to understand this integral?

Comment: Standard Gaussian integral - complete the square.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake I am familiar with the Standard Gaussian integral where the limit of $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. What I am puzzled is the $\mathcal{D}\pi$, it’s limit and other things as I point in the last paragraph of my post. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathcal{D}\pi = \prod_x \mathrm{d}\pi(x)$ and the limits are all negative infinity to infinity. In other words, you're integrating over the space of all functions with support on the specified part of space-time (specified in the integral inside the exponential function).

Comment: I just want to clarify the integration should have $\sqrt{2\pi}$, is it dropped due to it is just a phase change?

Comment: @LiChiyan Which integration do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, there are 2 issues:

1. It is safest to [Wick rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) $t_E=it_M$ to make the [Gaussian integrals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368186/2451) exponentially damped rather than oscillatory. (NB: Don't also Wick rotate the momentum field $\pi_M=i\pi_E$, cf. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/328773/2451).)
2. Truncate spacetime to a finite large box and discretize it. The result of the Gaussians integrations will be a number ${\cal N}$ that doesn't depend on any physically important parameters, but diverge in the continuum limit. Define the path integral measure ${\cal D}\pi$ to contain the reciprocal constant ${\cal N}^{-1}$.