# Constrained Hamiltonian systems: spin 1/2 particle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, supersymmetry, constrained-dynamics

I am trying to apply the Constrained Hamiltonian Systems theory on relativistic particles. For what concerns the scalar particle there is no issue. Indeed, I have the action
\begin{equation}
S=-m\int d\tau \sqrt{-\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}_\mu}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
and computing the momentum 
\begin{equation}
p_\mu=\frac{m\dot{x}_\mu}{\sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
I see that it satisfies the constraint $p_\mu p^\mu+m^2=0$. I then proceed to quantize the system with the Dirac method.

I am finding issues with the relativistic massless spin 1/2 particle. Indeed, it is described by the space-time coordinates $x^\mu$ and by the **real** grassmann variables $\psi^\mu$, according to my notes. The action should take the form
\begin{equation}
S=\int d\tau \space \dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}_\mu+\frac{i}{2}\psi_\mu\dot{\psi}^\mu\tag{3}
\end{equation}
which exhibits a supersymmetry on the worldline, the supersymmetric conserved charge being $Q=\psi^\mu p_\mu$. 
According to the lecturer I should find the constraints
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{1}{2}p^2, \quad Q=\psi^\mu p_\mu\tag{4}
\end{equation}
i.e. the dynamics on the phase space should take place on hypersurfaces $$H=0, Q=0.\tag{5}$$

**My question**:
How can I derive these constraints? They should arise simply with the definition of momenta, but, having no constants to work with, I'm left with
\begin{equation}
p_\mu=\dot{x}_\mu\\
\Pi_\mu=\frac{i}{2}\dot{\psi}_\mu\tag{6}
\end{equation}
and I don't know what to do with them. I see that, in principle, the first constraint is obtained by setting $m=0$ in the constraint of the scalar particle for example, but what if I want to derive it without the previous knowledge? And what about $Q$?

**Edit**:
By intuition, **knowing** that the model exhibits a ${\cal N}=1$ supersymmetry, I may understand that the dynamics must take place on a surface such that $H=const$ and $Q=const$ (then I could set the constant to zero without lack of generality?), being $Q$ and $H$ conserved charges. Is it the only way to find these constraints? Should I need this previous knowledge about supersymmetry to study the model? I think I should be able to find these constraints just by looking at the Lagrangian itself.

Comment: $\Pi_{\mu}$ is $\frac{i}{2}\psi_{\mu}$. The canonical momenta of fermions are themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. We consider here the massless case $m=0$. Let us start from the Lagrangian$^1$
   $$L_0~=~\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e} +\frac{i}{2}\psi_{\mu}\dot{\psi}^{\mu} \tag{A}$$
   with an einbein field $e$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451) Phys.SE post. If we introduce the momentum
   $$ p_{\mu}~=~\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}
   ~=~\frac{\dot{x}_{\mu}}{e},\tag{B}$$
   the corresponding Legendre transformation $\dot{x}^{\mu}\leftrightarrow p_{\mu}$ yields a first-order Lagrangian
   $$\begin{align} L_1~=~&p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu} +\frac{i}{2}\psi_{\mu}\dot{\psi}^{\mu}-eH, \cr 
   H~:=~&\frac{p^2}{2}.\end{align} \tag{C}$$
   This explains OP's first constraint $H\approx 0$, which is indirectly due to world-line (WL) reparametrization invariance, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449169/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. It is unnecessary to introduce momentum for the fermions $\psi^{\mu}$ as the Lagrangian $L_1$ is already on first-order form, cf. the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075).
3. The Lagrangian $L_1$ has a global super [quasisymmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451). The infinitesimal transformation
   $$\begin{align} \delta x^{\mu}~=~&i\varepsilon\psi^{\mu},  \cr 
   \delta \psi^{\mu}~=~&-\varepsilon p^{\mu},  \cr 
   \delta p^{\mu}~=~& 0 , \cr 
   \delta e~=~& 0, \end{align}  \tag{D}$$
   changes the Lagrangian with a total derivative
   $$\begin{align} \delta L_1~=~&\ldots~=~i\dot{\varepsilon}Q+\frac{i}{2}\frac{d(\varepsilon Q)}{d\tau},  \cr Q~:=~&p_{\mu}\psi^{\mu}, \end{align}\tag{E}$$
   for $\tau$-independent Grassmann-odd infinitesimal parameter $\varepsilon$.
4. OP's other constraint $Q\approx0$ arises by gauging the SUSY, i.e. $\delta L_1$ should be a total derivative for an arbitrary function $\varepsilon(\tau)$. On reason to do this is given in Ref. 2 below eq. (3.3):

   > *Because of the time component of the field $\psi^{\mu}$ there is a possibility that negative norm states may appear in the physical spectrum. In order to decouple them we require an additional invariance and, inspired by the Neveu-Schwarz-Ramond model, it seems natural to demand invariance under local supergauge transformations.*
5. Concretely, we impose $Q\approx0$ with the help of a Lagrange multiplier $\chi$. This leads to the Lagrangian
   $$\begin{align} L_2~=~&L_1-i \chi Q\cr
   ~=~&p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu} +\frac{i}{2}\psi_{\mu}\dot{\psi}^{\mu}-eH - i \chi Q .\end{align}\tag{F}$$
6. Let us mention for completeness that in order to have gauged super quasisymmetry of the new Lagrangian $L_2$, the previous transformation $\delta e= 0$ needs to be modified into
   $$\begin{align} \delta e~=~&2i\chi\varepsilon, \cr
    \delta \chi~=~&\dot{\varepsilon}.\end{align}\tag{G}$$
7. An alternative perspective is the replacement
   $$L_2~=~ L_1|_{\dot{x}\to  Dx}\tag{H}$$
   of the ordinary derivative
   $$\dot{x}^{\mu}\quad\longrightarrow\quad  Dx^{\mu}~:=~\dot{x}^{\mu} -i\chi \psi^{\mu}\tag{I}$$
   with a gauge-covariant derivative $Dx^{\mu}$. Here $\chi$ is a compensating gauge field. The gauge-covariant derivative transforms as
   $$ \delta Dx^{\mu}~=~i\varepsilon(\dot{\psi}^{\mu}-\chi p^{\mu}).\tag{J}$$

References:

1. F. Bastianelli, [*Constrained hamiltonian systems and relativistic particles*](http://www-th.bo.infn.it/people/bastianelli/2-ch6-FT2-2017.pdf), 2017 lecture notes; Section 2.2.
2. L. Brink, P. Di Vecchia & P. Howe, [Nucl. Phys. B118 (1977) 76](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(77)90364-9); Below eq. (3.3).
3. C.M. Hull & J.-L. Vazquez-Bello, [arXiv:hep-th/9308022](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9308022); Chapter 2, p. 7-8.
4. O. Corradini & C. Schubert, *Spinning Particles in QM & QFT,* [arXiv:1512.08694](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08694); Subsection 1.5.2.

--

$^1$ *Conventions:* We use the Minkowski sign convention $(-,+,+,+)$ and we work in units where $c=1$.